# Registro con firebase en Kotlin con patrón mvvm

Tags: firebase, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-auth

Llevo unos días mirándome el tema del mvvm en Kotlin, aplicado sobre todo a firebase.
Tengo una duda sobre cómo poder realizar de forma correcta un registro en firebase con user y pass con el siguiente código:

ViewModel:

```
val regUser = fun(email: String, password: String): LiveData<Resource<Boolean>> {
    val registeredUser = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())

        try {
            val alreadyRegistered: Resource<Boolean> = useCase.registerUser(email, password)
            // cuando tengo datos para enviar a la activity
            emit(alreadyRegistered)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // cuando algo ha fallado
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            Log.e("ERROR", e.message.toString())
        }
    }

    return registeredUser
}
```

Esto llama a un caso de uso que sólo reenvía los datos a un repositorio con la siguiente información:

```
override suspend fun registerUser(email: String, password: String): Resource<Boolean> {

    // Firebase create user with email and pass
    val result = mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    // Waiting until result is complete
    while(!result.isComplete) {
    }

    return if (result.isSuccessful) {
        Resource.Success(true)
    } else Resource.Success(false)

}
```

Mientras en que en la activity, únicamente recogemos el resultado del viewModel:

```
        mainViewModel.regUser(binding.txtUsername.text.toString(), binding.txtPassword.text.toString()).observe(this, {
            when(it) {
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    Log.d("Sergio", "Estamos cargando el registro del usuario")
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Log.d("Sergio", "Success: ${it.data}" )
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    Log.w("Sergio", it.exception.message.toString())
                }
            }
        })
```

Mi pregunta es, cómo podría hacer que este código funcionase quitando este while del código del repositorio?

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La versión completa de kotlin coroutines (`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2`), trae una función [await()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) para usar en estos casos:

```
override suspend fun registerUser(email: String, password: String) = try {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
    Resource.Success(true)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Resource.Success(false)
}
```